# Pods-Alamofire: Swift is not supported for static libraries

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, cocoapods, alamofire

I have a project running on Swift 1.2 and iOS 8.4. 
After the update to Swift 2 and iOS 9, I did "pod update" to update my pods. 
Now there is an Pods-Alamofire error: "Swift is not supported for static libraries."
Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Can you show us how your pod file looks like ?

Comment: platform :ios, '8.0'

pod 'PixateFreestyle'
pod 'Alamofire', '~> 2.0'
pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 2.0'
pod 'MZFormSheetController'
pod 'SwiftSpinner'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `use_frameworks!` below platform on your pod file. This way your pod will be added as framework and not as static library

Comment: Thank you, that solved the problem. I had to update my CocoaPods first, then add use_frameworks!.

Answer (score 6):

If you are using cocoapods, make sure that you are using the right version of Alamofire

```
pod 'Alamofire', '~> 2.0' //2.0 is currently the latest version
```

Also make sure you are using `use_frameworks!` so your Profile should look like this:

```
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

pod 'Alamofire', '~> 2.0'
```

The `use_framworks!` part tells CocoaPods that your project is using frameworks instead of static libraries.

In order to use Pods written in Swift, you must explicitly include use_frameworks! to opt into using frameworks. If you forget to include this, and CocoaPods detects you’re trying to use a Swift CocoaPod, you’ll get an error when you try to install the pods.

If you’ve only ever programmed in Swift, this may look a bit strange − that’s because the Podfile is actually written in Ruby. You don’t need to know Ruby to use CocoaPods, but you should be aware that even minor text errors will typically cause CocoaPods to throw an error.

Credit: [Ray Wenderlich](http://www.raywenderlich.com/97014/use-cocoapods-with-swift)

Comment: I am using version 2.0.